# Asus Q324UA Notebook - Unable to clear BIOS

Tags: bios, laptop-repair, repair

I have a Asus Q324UA Notebook that I have unfortunately forgotten the administrator password to the BIOs on. I attempted to simply remove a CMOS battery from the motherboard, but the latptop doesn't have one (yes, I completely disassembled and reassembled it several times), it's a `60NB0C00-MB8000` Asus Q324UA motherboard. Some sites say for ASUS laptops that you can hit ALT+R on the password screen, and that would show a recovery option, but that doesn't appear to be the case for this one.

I also attempted an "auto detect" BIOS firmware where you put the BIOS firmware file on a FAT32 USB drive, plug in, and startup, but this had no effect. I used the BIOs *.312 file straight from [the ASUS website](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/Q324UAK/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

I m able to boot into my CentOS installation on it OK. But I'm unable to get into the BIOs to change boot settings or anything. Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot clear modern BIOS (UEFI) Passwords by removing the battery.

BIOS (UEFI) Password are designed to be secure.

Contact ASUS Support as they may need to replace the BIOS Chip to enable proper use again.