# unable to access BIOS on toshiba c55

Tags: bios

Ok, have a toshiba c55 b5101, had ubuntu installed on it, dropped a crockpot on it and cracked the screen. Put the thing in the corner and forgot about it. A couple years later, I'm thinking I'll change the screen and get it running again. Powering up, it goes from the Toshiba logo to enter password...none of my passwords work...and pressing f12, f8, and the rest of the f keys does nothing on startup. Goes straight from logo to password...Replaced battery, (had it out for 5-6 days while waiting for new one to arrive)this may be one with no cmos, (if there is one, where the hell is it?) the main battery fulfills that function. So, whats a poor boy to do? This is one of the projects in my Google Pro Support Cert Class I'm currently working on. Thx for your replies

Comment: It appears to me to have come with windows 8 so a decade old and broken. It will cost you more to fix than it is worh.

Comment: Knowledge is priceless...don't much care what it is worth, so long as I can gain knowledge form the journey... So, anyone have any ideas? If it does have a cmos, where is it? If not, how to clear the BIOS password.

Comment: There is nothing you can do without replacing the screen and broken parts. Nothing.,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asus Q324UA Notebook - Unable to clear BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1694669/asus-q324ua-notebook-unable-to-clear-bios)

Comment: Have you tried holding F2 down *before* powering up, and keeping depressed while powering up?

Comment: No function keys have any effect. Goes straight from Toshiba logo into password...

Comment: Update...found the JCMOS,did the flat screwdriver trick across the contact points, still no joy. Maybe I'm doing it incorrectly...does power need to be on, or no power or battery...